# Is there a way to use Server.MapPath in a class in my asp.net application

Tags: c#

I have a log.txt file on the root of my application. I would like to be able to have my log class be able to access this file and write to it. But i am not sure how to tell it the correct path of the file in my code. Thanks for any help

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
    {
         Log(e.ToString(),w);
         w.Close();
    }
```

Comment: better put that log in App_Data, probably your app doesn't have rights to write in root folder

Comment: And Consider: File.AppendAllText(filename, msg);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
Server.MapPath("~/log.txt")
```

to get the full file name.

**Update:**

If you're not inside an ASP page, but in a regular class, try:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/log.txt")
```

**Update 2:**
It looks like you are trying to make your own logging solution. You may consider using an existing solution, like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: I cannot its a class not a asp.net class. If you can can you show me how?

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` is not available in the `View` in `MVC6` It's just `Context` now, but no `Server`

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would get that Path from the Web.config .
And it would be a physical file path, not a relative URL path. No MapPath needed.

The easiest way: create it with the Settings designer tool and read it as

```
 string fname = Properties.Settings.Default.LogFile;
```

Comment: Ok can you give me an example, lets say i would like to save it to my root directory.

Comment: Application root or Diskdrive root?  Btw, neither is a good choice for a log file.